# How to get the size of a Search Controller's Text Field (for sizing the placeholder)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchController`, with one of those search bars that resizes when you tap it (ie, it gets smaller because the "Cancel" button appears on the right side). I want to truncate the placeholder text based on the length of the text field in my search bar. However, I'm only able to get the length of the entire search bar, not the text field.

This is my current implementation:

```
if let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
   textFieldInsideSearchBar.frame.width ...
```

However, this `textFieldInsideSearchBar.frame.width` seems to be the width of the entire search bar, and not the text field. The view hierarchy tells me that there is a property called the `UITextFieldContentView`, which seems to be the one I want, but `UITextField` has no property `ContentView`.

Comment: When do you call the code? Calling it from UISearchControllerDelegate didPresentSearchController should give you the correct width of the UITextField. At least on iPhone 7 I get 279 from didPresentSearchController and 343 from didDismissSearchController. The width of the search bar is 375 in both cases.